# How to fix app layout shrinking on iOS after upgrading RN version from 0.63.4 to 0.71.1?

Tags: ios, react-native, shrink

After upgrading **RN version** from **0.63.4** to **0.71.1**, app layout shrink like the image bellow.
I'm using **Xcode 14.3**, run app in **Rosetta simulator**

Do you have any idea about this issue?

```
Some info about environment 
  System:
    OS: macOS 13.1
    CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
    Memory: 3.14 GB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 19.0.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v19.0.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.19.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v19.0.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.03.13.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
    Xcode: 14.3/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 17.0.5 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
    react-native: 0.71.1 => 0.71.1 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
```

[App layout shrink on iOS after upgrade to RN 0.71](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DShdX.png)

I did try to upgrade version of these following dependencies:

```
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.12",    
"@react-navigation/stack": "6.3.16",     
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.3",    
"react-native-screens": "3.20.0",
```

I expect the app's frame is full screen on iOS , not shrink
[App layout shrink on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOWfP.png)

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is app did not found the Launch Image so it run default

How to fix:

Step 1: Create `Launch Screen.storyboard`

Step 2: Select `Lunch Screen File` point to `Launch Screen.storyboard` have just been created

Step 3: Update background color of Launch Screen , then reload app and it work normally

Answer (score 0):

Open the Xcode Project,

Go to the General tab
Then under `Supported Destinations` ensure the device you are testing/running on is on the list. e.g `iPad`[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGIkC.png) is on the list